# Find the basis of $V$ where $V$ is the subset of the solutions to a ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $V$ the subset of the solutions to the differential equation

$$\frac{d^{3}x}{dt^{3}}-x =0$$

such that $x(0)=0$. Prove that $V$ is a vectorial space and find a basis for $V$.

I found the general solution to be
$$x(t)= c_{1}e^{t} +c_{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}\cos (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t) + c_{3}e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)$$
and because every solution that belongs to $V$ is such that $x(0)=0$, we have that $c_{1} = -c_{2}$, then if $x\in V$ it has the form
$$x(t)= c_{1}(e^{t} -e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}\cos (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)) + c_{3}e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t).$$

I  prove that $V$ is a vectorial space, I have doubts about the basis, I think the basis is $v_{1}(t) = e^{t} -e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}\cos (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)$ and $v_{2}(t)= e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)$, am I right?

Comment: Looks like you dropped something at the very end.  $v_1(t) = e^{t} - e^{-\frac 12t}\cos \left( \frac  {\sqrt 3}{2} t \right)$

Comment: @DougM yeah, I forgot to write it, thanks

Comment: Have you proved $\{v_1(t), v_2(t)\}$ is linearly independent?